# how can do an 'OR' search in NEO4J cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j db with different labels on the nodes such as a:Banker , b:Customer. each has an email property I want to search for an email but but not search the entire db. So I want to do something like this Match(a:Banker {email: '123@mymail.com'}) OR Match (b:Customer {email:'123@mymail.com'}). There are constraints on email for both labels but I don't want each label to have the same email so before I add a node I need to determine if the email exist in either Banker or Customer nodes. I suspect this can be done in a very efficient scalable way that would not leave the user staring at a spinner when trying to add the one millionth record.....any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Basically as Liam says. If a bank and customer can't have the same email, than you will need to add an additional label to put on both nodes (something like person, client, or entity), and create a unique constraint on that more generic label. Otherwise, just put a Unique constraint on the email property of each of those nodes, and the Cypher planner will auto-magically switch to using the Unique Constraint index for the search/enforcement. (I would argue the later is more correct. It's harder to mess up, and a Banker usually also is a Customer (but not always))

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the comment and put it as an answer with more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How I would do it is have an addition label 'Person' on all Bankers and Customers.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (b:Person) ASSERT p.Email IS UNIQUE
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (b:Banker) ASSERT p.Email IS UNIQUE
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (b:Customer) ASSERT p.Email IS UNIQUE

CREATE (b:Person:Banker {Email: "123@mymail.com"})
CREATE (b:Person:Customer {Email: "321@mymail.com"})
CREATE (c:Person:Customer {Email: "123@mymail.com"})
```

The last one will fail as a Person/Banker already has the same email. You can then also search MATCH (p:Person {Email: "123@mymail.com"}) or even b:Banker, c:Customer

You can also do (p:Person:Customer:Banker) if a person is all three.

It will also allow you to do [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/merge/) which creates an entry if it doesn't already exist.

Since you already have a database you can do:

```
MATCH(b:Banker)
SET b:Person

MATCH(c:Customer)
SET c:Person
```

Comment: Good approach. Would MATCH (b:Person {email: "123@mymail"}) be the fastest way to search?

Comment: MATCH (b:Person {email: "123@mymail"}) RETURN b LIMIT 1

Comment: @Liam...Am I to understand that the search will continue to the end without the LIMIT even though given the constraint there should only be 1?

Comment: I have feeling it will stop at one if it is a constraint. I just do it out of habit. No harm in testing both.

Answer (score 1):

1. A somewhat "safer" approach than @Liam's would be to just have the `Person` label, without the `Banker` and `Customer` labels. That way, it would be harder to accidentally create/merge a node without the `Person` label, since that would be the only label for a person. Also, this approach would not require 2 (or 3) uniqueness checks every time you added a person.

   With this approach, you could also add `isCustomer` and `isBanker` boolean properties, as needed, and create indexes on `:Person(isCustomer)` and `:Person(isBanker)` to quickly locate customers versus bankers.
2. Now, having said the above, I wonder if you really need the `isCustomer` and `isBanker` properties (or the `Customer` and `Banker` labels) at all. That is, the fact that a `Person` node is a banker and/or a customer may be derivable from that node's relationships. It seems reasonable for your data model to contain `Bank` nodes with relationships between them and people. For example, in the following data model, `b` is a banker at "XYZ Bank", `c` is a customer, and `bc` is both:

   ```
   (b:Person)-[:WORKS_AT]->(xyz:Bank {id:123, name: 'XYZ Bank'}),
   (c:Person)-[:BANKS_AT]->(xyz),
   (bc:Person)-[:BANKS_AT]->(xyz)<-[:WORKS_AT]-(bc)
   ```

   This query would find all bankers:

   ```
   MATCH (banker:Person)-[:WORKS_AT]->(:Bank)
   RETURN banker;
   ```

   This would find all customers:

   ```
   MATCH (banker:Person)-[:BANKS_AT]->(:Bank)
   RETURN banker;
   ```

   This would find all bankers who are also customers at the same bank:

   ```
   MATCH (both:Person)-[:WORKS_AT]->(:Bank)<-[:BANKS_AT]-(both)
   RETURN both;
   ```

Comment: @cybersam....I think I will need the labels at minimum for clarity and readability. My need is speed. When a new :Person attempts to register I have to check if the email submitted already exist either as a :Banker or a :Customer....so to ensure scalability  I need the fastest way to check if the submitted email is already in use....There are also cases where I need just to find all bankers or all customers.....wouldn't the extra node :Bank require more memory also?

Comment: Option 2 was proposed on the assumption that your data model already had `Bank` nodes -- which seemed reasonable since you are dealing with bankers and their customers.  But do you have any use cases that require any relationships at all? If not, then using a graph DB may be overkill.